# OpenCL workers count always 1

Tags: opencl

I am new to GPU development , and i was wondering about how many workers (threads) concurrently executes my kernel so i used below kernel

```
kernel void helloWorld(global int* result) 
{     
      int gid = 0;
      gid = get_local_id(0);
      if (gid > result[0])
      {
        result[0] = gid;
      }
}
```

but when running on core i7 intel result[0] is always 0 ; and when run on nvidia GPU it always 0

Comment: It can be left up to the runtime by specifying NULL for local work group size. However, this code is not right because the access to `result[0]` is not atomic. All threads will read the initial value (presumably 0 if you cleared the buffer before running the kernel) then writing their value, which results in a race condition. Instead, have each work item write it's local ID into a buffer position indexed by it's global ID. The results will vary by device.

Answer (score 0):

Opencl divides threads on the device into work groups.
A work group is settled on the same execution unit (note several workgroups can be on the execution unit)
It is possible to let the compiler decide the size of the work groups.

However you pick a number of total threads when starting the kernel.
example:

```
clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(command_queue, cl_exec, 1, NULL, &tasksize, &local_size_in, 0, NULL, NULL)
```

tasksize = total number of threads
local_size = number of threads in a group

so tasksize / local_size is the number of workgroups you will have.

If you write NULL instead of local_size the compiler decides about the size of work groups.

There are several contraints for the local_size.
Take a look here: [cl api](https://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/clEnqueueNDRangeKernel.html)

In my experience the optimal result is mostly the one the compiler choses.
This can be different in complex cases, where you have specific knowledge what happens at runtime, which is not available at compile time.

Also all devices have a max work group size.

```
CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_GROUP_SIZE
```